# Unable to build Cython extension

Tags: python, c++, gcc, cython, setuptools

I am trying to build python extension with Cython with the following project structure:

```
include/
    algorithm/
        LessonplanScheduler.hpp
src/
    LessonplanScheduler.cpp
    GenAlgorithm.cpp
    GenAlgorithm.hpp
    LessonplanGenAlgorithm.cpp
    LessonplanGenAlgorithm.cpp
__init__.py
algorithm.pyx
LessonplanScheduler.pxd
setup.py
```

`setup.py` looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
      name='Lessonplan scheduler algorithm',
      ext_modules=cythonize(
          [
              Extension(
                  name="algorithm",
                  include_dirs=["./include/algorithm"],
                  library_dirs=["./src"],
                  sources=["algorithm.pyx", "algorithm.cpp"],
              )
          ],
          language_level=3
      ),
      requires=['Cython'],
)
```

After running `python ./setup.py build_ext --inplace`, I am getting `build` folder in project root and `algorithm.cpp` also there. But `.so` file is not built because of `multiple definition` errors:

```
Compiling algorithm.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing algorithm.pyx
running build_ext
building 'algorithm' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I./include/algorithm -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c algorithm.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I. -I./include/algorithm -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c algorithm.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
g++ -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o -L./src -L/usr/local/lib -lpython3.7m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `__pyx_module_is_main_algorithm'; build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o: in function `PyInit_algorithm':
/backend/backend/algorithm/algorithm.cpp:1966: multiple definition of `PyInit_algorithm'; build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/algorithm.o:/backend/backend/algorithm/algorithm.cpp:1966: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

The problem, as I suppose, lives in `algorithm.cpp` file, so it is probably caused by wrong build configuration. What should I do to fix the problem and what would be the best way to build the project?

Comment: If you look at the compile output closely you will see it compiling `algorithm.cpp` twice and linking `algorithm.o` twice. From a quick look through the documentation I think you're only supposed to specify the .pyx file under `sources`.

Comment: You have right, but g++ without `algorithm.cpp` returns another error - undefined symbol 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from algorithm.algorithm import run_algorithm
ImportError: /backend/backend/algorithm/algorithm.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN11lessonplans12GenAlgorithmE`

Comment: You should probably add `LessonplanGenAlgorithm.cpp` back to the sources then, together with the other .cpp files. Just not algorithm.cpp.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! After adding all cpp files it works.